# Why is R.raw.sound (.sound is just an example) or R.id.idName considered an integer?

Tags: java, android

Just curious, why are these files considered an integer?
What makes them an integer when they are pass on the R.raw or R.id?

Comment: this is good article to under stand it  : http://knowledgefolders.com/akc/display?url=DisplayNoteIMPURL&reportId=2883&ownerUserId=satya

Comment: this is same question as you would ask what makes adresses of ram be represented as hex codes

Answer (score 1):

> why are these files considered an integer?

they are not considered integer.

> What makes them an integer when they are pass on the R.raw or R.id?

at compile time, Android reads the content of `res/` and generates a class called R, which contains a bunch of static inner class. Those classes contain the unique identifiers that represent your `res/`, and allow you to reference it at runtime.